# Ionic build fails - cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-fcm

```
 Task :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
/app/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/ionicframework/cordova/webview/IonicWebViewEngine.java:11: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
                                 ^
/app/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/ionicframework/cordova/webview/IonicWebViewEngine.java:137: error: cannot find symbol
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
     ^
  symbol:   class RequiresApi
  location: class IonicWebViewEngine.ServerClient
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2 errors
```

after installing cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated

Answer (score 0):

After removing webview plugin build was successful.